# fabric-client vs fabric-network vs fabric-gateway

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying develop my first Hyperledger fabric application. I'm really confused ,should one use fabric-client or fabric-network or fabric-gateway for developing client SDK in node?

Answer (score 0):

If you are (or can be) using Fabric v2.4 or later, I would strongly recommend using fabric-gateway. If using an older version of Fabric (or if you require some capabilities not available in fabric-gateway) then fabric-network. I would suggest avoiding fabric-client, which is end-of-life after Fabric v1.4.

There is some information on the positioning of the different client API implementation in the Hyperledger Fabric documentation:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.4/sdk_chaincode.html